# Tr05 gps device sends data xxU!3p. How to i decode this and what is meaning of this string in php

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to develop a platform for TR05 devices where they send the data and I need to parse it in the location coordinates. I have done the handshake stuff and  device is sending the data, I can't able to parse the string. The string I am receiving is: xxU!3p

Comment: This has nothing to do with php

Comment: Then what will i do

Comment: Hello, welcome. Please, have a good read onhttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - then, believe me, your chances to get help will be bigger. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am too familiar with your TR05 device, but you might want to check you language setting on the device itself. It might be communication in Chinese.

Comment: Its configure with english language

Comment: I'm sorry. I think this is not a real answer, but a comment. Congratulations, anyway, for your positive initiative. Best.